# AMQP / RabbitMQ sender in AVR (Arduino)

Tags: arduino, rabbitmq, amqp, avr

Has an [AMQP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Message_Queuing_Protocol) message sender been implemented on AVR / Arduino?

- Is this possible, given the limited space available on the [ATmega328](http://www.atmel.com/devices/atmega328.aspx)
- I am not looking for a full implementation. Just a bare-bones "send a message". Receiving messages would be nice too, but is not essential.

Comment: Related discussion on RabbitMQ mailing list: [Simplest possible embedded message producer](http://lists.rabbitmq.com/pipermail/rabbitmq-discuss/2012-March/018950.html)

Answer (score 5):

Do you need exactly ACMQ or any MQ protocol for message exchange? There's an [Arduino client](http://knolleary.net/arduino-client-for-mqtt/) for [MQTT](http://mqtt.org/) — a protocol designed for embedded devices.

Comment: RabbitMQ now supports MQTT via an adapter, too. So try using MQTT on the AVR/Arduino and publishing to RabbitMQ, for example.